# URL decoding of JS-encoded Japanese characters in Java 6

Tags: java, javascript, urldecode, utf8-decode, encodeuricomponent

I am using **encodeURIComponent** in javascript(assuming this does UTF-8 encoding) to encode a variable which could contain characters like =, +, etc. This is sent as POST to my servlet where I decode it.

This works well with English but when used with Japanese string - "バスケット", this converts to some special character sequence like this - "Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ¹Ã£ÂÂ±Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ"

I am using following java 1.6 code to decode it but it doesn't work -

```
String ID = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(assignedID,"UTF-8");
```

where assignedID contains special character sequence. The above code returns me - "Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ¹Ã£ÂÂ±Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂ"

Comment: `java.net.URLDecoder.decode("%E3%83%90%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88","UTF-8");` works for me. Maybe your `assignedId` didn't get the right value?

Comment: @Griddoor I am suspecting that as you can see the Japanese characters are changed to that junk sequence rather than something like %E3%B3.... But then I think encodeURIComponent does UTF-8 encoding unless if I am wrong about this assumption or if it doesn't work well with Japanese characters here?

Answer (score 0):

In your post, is the string you're sending is being sent as part of the `URL` or as part of the POST body. Its mostly the part of `POST` body, try adding (to jsp):

```
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>
```

Comment: It is part of POST body. I am working on abstract layer so I need to if I can set the character encoding explicitly. Do you think it is not doing UTF-8 encoding? Isn't encodeURIComponent function in javascript supposed to do UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Normally it should be `UTF-8` encoding.